# The Quotient of a free group on two generators by commutator

Tags: group-theory

Let F be a free group on $\{ x_1 ,x_2 \}$ in the category of groups. Let $G=\langle a\rangle \times \langle b\rangle$. I showed that the map $\theta :x_1 \to a$ and $x_2 \to b$ extends to a homomorphism $\bar{\theta}$ of $F$ onto $G$ and then $F' \subset \ker \bar{\theta}$, but I don't know how to show $\ker\bar{\theta}\subset F'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every element $w$ of $F$ can be written in the form $w=x^{u_1}y^{v_1}x^{u_2}y^{v_2} \dots x^{u_n} y^{v_n}$ with some $n\in\Bbb N$ and $u_i, v_i\in\Bbb Z$.

This $w$ is mapped to $\left(a^{\sum_i u_i}, \ b^{\sum_i v_i}\right)$, thus $w\in \ker\bar\theta \iff \sum_i u_i=0=\sum_i v_i$.

Use e.g. induction on $n$ to prove that in such case, $w$ must be the product of pure commutators.